# Firebase Auth to existing custom login flow with Phone Number

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an app which is already published on the play store and uses some firebase databases whose security rules are public. So in order to make the rules private and fit in the security rules. I would have to implement Firebase Auth.

So my app login flow works as in identifying the user with their phone number OTP verification.

First, I don't want the user to change their login flow. Like I don't want to integrate Social Login.

So is there a way I can use [Firebase Phone Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) to my existing flow and get the uid of the user so that in the Firebase DB rules I can use that uid for my auth?

Please help me! I am stuck at this and couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you use a phone number OTP system that is not Firebase Authentication to identify your users.

There is no way to tie that existing flow to Firebase's phone number authentication that I can think of.

The two options that come to mind:

- Replace your existing authentication system with Firebase Authentication, and map their new (Firebase) UID to the previous ID system.
- Keep using your own phone number verification, and [mint a custom Firebase token for your users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) based on that, then [use *that* to sign in to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth). Generating custom tokens can only be done in a trusted environment though.